# Difference between Indiscipline and Undiscipline?

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference

What is the difference between the two words: Indiscipline and Undiscipline?

Is seems both are having the same meaning. Can you explain the difference between the two by using them in sentences.

Comment: I doubt *Indiscipline* is commonly used at all. You should add some example sentences to your question. It is possible there is a better way to say it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are both nouns and both mean *a lack of discipline*. However, the word *undiscipline* is far less common than *indiscipline*. The latter can be found in most dictionaries, while most dictionaries will not contain *undiscipline*.

Far more common is the use of *undiscipline**d*** as an adjective. Though even in this context it would probably be more idiomatic to use a negation of the word *disciplined* instead, compare:

> - He is rather undisciplined.
> - He is **not very** disciplined.

Answer (score 0):

From Oxford and Cambridge dictionaries, there is no adjective indisciplined. I've just heard ex-Labour UK politician Ed Balls use indisciplined in a live election discussion, late 2019 (to describe PM Boris Johnson). The word appears in the Free Dictionary online, but as an adjective, Cambridge and Oxford only list undisciplined.

As for nouns, neither Oxford nor Cambridge list undiscipline. Personally, despite the answer above saying it's an uncommon word, I have never come across such a word, undiscipline.

So according to these two fairly authoritative dictionaries the only words there are indiscipline and undisciplined.

However, Chambers is also amongst the authoritative dictionaries, and it lists the alternate adjective to undisciplined, indisciplined (dating from 18th Century), but unsurprisingly to me, along with Oxford and Cambridge dictionaries, doesn't recognise undiscipline.

Answer (score 0):

I am not expert in English language but I use both the words, Indisciplined and Undisciplined to express different character of persons.

Indisciplined is by Default. It's Core Character of some persons. They can not be disciplined.

Undisciplined is by Design. Parants make their children Undisciplined by pampering. They can be disciplined.